# Color-based antonym of "blues"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

### Context

The definition of "blues" being used here is:

> feelings of melancholy, sadness, or depression.

[image]

### Question

Is there an antonym of this word, but based on a color name? The antonym would be synonymous with such words as *optimistic*, *joie de vivre*, *delighted*, *cheerful*, etc.

### Example sentences

- Sridhar has got the ____ [or, Sridhar is ___ [a color adjective]]; as he sees no reason not to enjoy this moment, regardless of situation he is in.
- John has been diagnosed with cancer [or whatever]; yet he remains optimistic and delighted at the ongoings of life. John has got the ___; or, John is ___ [a color adjective].

Comment: Perhaps *he got a 'golden' chance to enjoy....* or something?

Comment: Isn't yellow the chromatic opposite of blue?

Comment: I've added one more example sentence to clarify the word context, as well as its usage (which applies even when you are in an unfortunate situation -- homeless, sick, in prison, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will *peachy* do?

> **Peachy** (adj):
>
> 1. Resembling a peach, especially in color or texture.
> 2. [Informal] Splendid; fine.

[[American Heritage Dictionary]](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=peachy)

Answer (score 4):

The colour **pink** is associated with health and happiness:

From [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/In+the+Pink)

> **in the pink**
> Healthy; in good condition.

and [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tickled+pink) also has

> **tickled pink**
> Very pleased with someone or something.

So perhaps

> Sridhar is tickled pink; he sees no reason not to enjoy this moment, regardless of the situation he is in.

Comment: 'In the pink' is the reverse metaphor, good spot, but there's not a word that will fit OP's sample sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree, "in the pink" is fine but I've never heard a song including the line "I got the pinks real good"

Comment: The idiom "everything's rosy" exists though, although it's not that common.

Comment: @BoldenBen but not "Sridhar has got the roses." Sometimes the asker is too restrictive about how the word will be used. On StackOverflow there is the concept of [the XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where OP asks *this* but actually wants to do *that*.

Comment: The sample sentence doesn't necessarily need the phrase "has got the", as "is" (followed by an adjective) will also do. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I'd add that one important critieria is to capture the optimistic (as in, glass half full kind) nature of this emotion. One may even be sufferng from some health condition, yet feeling optimistic and delighted. This is where "in the pink" becomes tricky.

Comment: That's why I used the other phrase in my example sentence. It is a momentary thing.

Comment: Yea, I upvoted this answer - inasmuch as it is interesting and relevant (if not 100% yet) to hear and learn of all these color-based terms to describe feeling-states! I'll let this question simmer for some time to see what comes up.

Answer (score 2):

[Credit goes to Jens Petersen on Twitter](https://twitter.com/juhp/status/1322915005608517637)

**Melancholy** is dark blue, the opposite temperament is **Sanguine**: yellow

*EDIT*: Even though Jens described sanguine as "yellow", the dictionary definition below says it is "blood-red" (see comments for further context).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Saying someone is [**yellow²**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yellow) usually means they are a coward. It does not mean they are happy.

Comment: I don't know why Jens used yellow, sanguine is defined as **blood-red**. But, based on my intuition (don't know for sure), blood-red refers to intense passions - like love & anger, and not such much the unconditionally mirthful mood of cheerful optimism. Nevertheless, the word 'sanguine' is interesting - so I posted it as an answer (to be vetted among others). Updated the answer.

Comment: Obviously, one sense of _sanguine_ is blood red (but this sense is in a totally different register and probably even domain from 'Jo has got the blues'). But I can't see a definition for 'melancholy' here as 'dark blue', merely an observation.  'Jo is in the pink.' works far better than 'Jo is sanguine.' ('about his chances ...' or some other padding is the norm). And note that any antonym of the noun 'blues' needs to be a noun.

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone views the color, blue, in the same way.  So, to have the blues, may have more than one (inherent) meaning.

[The Color Psychology of Blue](https://www.verywellmind.com/the-color-psychology-of-blue-2795815)

As well, perhaps, even, some persons "love" being down, the underdog, etc.  To have the blues, but in a good way.